# Which Method for finding velocity of an object in the mirror is correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, kinematics, reflection, geometric-optics

My Professor asked a question,

> "A person is seen jogging in a rear view mirror of focal length $1$m. He is at a distance $39$m from the mirror. His jogging speed is given to be $5 \frac{m}{s}$. Find his speed as seen in the rear view mirror at that given point.". Here $u$ is object distance, $v$ is image distance and $f$ is focal length of the mirror.

**My Approach** : differentiating $\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{u}=\frac{1}{f} - (i)$ with respect to $t$ we get :

$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{v^2.du}{u^2dt}$

finding out $v$ using (i) and putting known values we can get the speed.

**My Professor's Approach** : The jogger will move some distance in 1 second. using (i) and calculating initial and final image position and hence dividing the distance traveled by time, we get the speed.

Both the methods are quite correct, but the problem is that they both yield different answers. My approach yielded $\frac{1}{320}$ while his approach calculated the speed to be $\frac{1}{280}$.

Is My Approach more accurate as it gives the instantaneous speed at the point whereas the professor's approach gives the average speed over 1 second (He did this calculation because it is given in the book :P). Or is his approach correct?

Comment: what is "(i)" ? That's not part of the lensmaker's formula.    What distances did your professor use for initial and final distance, and if you repeat his approach for , say 0.5 second instead of 1.0 second, what's the answer?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it must not be, we use rear view MIRROR not lens. It is simple relation of focal length, image distance and object distance of a mirror. he calculate the $v$ at t=0 and t=1 second. No I didn't try it, I am just asking if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: So try it -- do some work on your own to track down the source of the discrepancy.  And BTW the lensmaker's formula is applicable to curved mirrors as well as transmissive curved surfaces.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry sir, I am quite beginner into this thing. Also I know that the answer will get closer and closer to my answer as $ t $ tends to 0. But what should I do in the exam? The examiner's won't be provided with different answers, or will they?